# Call directive when component is visible

Tags: angular

I've created a directive to prevent scroll when certain components are visible (angular 12), here's my code:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, HostListener, Inject, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appRemoveScroll]'
})

export class RemoveScrollDirective {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
  ) { }

  @HostListener('visible', ['$event'])
  toggleNoScroll(visible: boolean) {
    console.log("called", visible)
    if (visible) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, 'no-scroll');
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.document.body, 'no-scroll');
    }
  }
}
```

I'm then adding this directive to a component which gets toggled using `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="displayProductLayover" id="product-layover" appRemoveScroll>
  <app-layover [heading]="layoverHeading">
    // More code here
```

I'm not getting any errors but this is not working, I'm not getting any console statements. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure about the directive, but you can do the same on `ngAfterViewInit()` method.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to create a directive because I want this behavior on a lot of different components

Comment: @AmolBorkar a directive is just a component with no template, so you can have your component extend a directive that implements `ngAfterViewInit()`

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements like `div` don't emit a `visible` event, so  `@HostListener('visible', ['$event'])` won't be called

Comment: So how can I detect if the `div` is visible inside the directive?